# How to make this effect in qt: adding a new lineedit when I click a button

Tags: qt

Newbie here. I want to have a GUI effect in my dock widget that whenever I click "add more" button or link, a new lineEdit field appears in the bottom.

I saw many software has something like

```
point-1 (_____,_____)
point-2 (_____,_____)
+ Add More Points
```

And when you click "`+ Add More Points`", a new point-3 will show up and wait for the input.

The code I have now is something like this:

```
#include "perfectPanel.hpp"

perfectPanel::perfectPanel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    readInfo();

    connect
    (
        btn_accept,
        SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this,
        SLOT(readInfo()),
        Qt::UniqueConnection
    );
}

// Destructor
perfectPanel::~perfectPanel()
{}

void perfectPanel::readInfo()
{
    xObject_ = vtkDoubleArray::New();
    yObject_ = vtkDoubleArray::New();
    xObject_->InsertNextValue( lineEdit_xObject01X->text().toDouble() );
    xObject_->InsertNextValue( lineEdit_xObject02X->text().toDouble() );
    yObject_->InsertNextValue( lineEdit_yObject01Y->text().toDouble() );
    yObject_->InsertNextValue( lineEdit_yObject02Y->text().toDouble() );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have now? And explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: Dear Zach, nothing wrong in the current code, I just want to add a new effect. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add that `+ Add More Points` button to the `perfectPanel` class. Let's say you've already done that with this declaration in your class' private data section:

`QPushButton* m_AddPoint;`

Now, connect the button's `clicked()` signal to some slot to add the point. From the example code, you seem to already know how to do this, so I won't go into the specifics. Let's say you've connected the button's click event to the `addPoint` function.

```
void perfectPanel::addPoint()
{
    /* The "this" argument is needed to prevent memory leaks */
    QLineEdit* Field = new QLineEdit(this);

    /* Your perfectPanel class has some layout where the existing LineEdit rows
       are. I'm assuming m_Layout is a pointer to that layout here. */
    m_Layout->addWidget(Field);
    Field->show();
}
```

Comment: Compile is okay, but when run, it complains `QLayout::parentWidget: A layout can only have another layout as a parent.` what should I do?

Comment: That sounds like your problem is with the initialization of the parent layout, not in the slot handler.

Comment: Sir would you please see the detailed problem description here,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166499/how-to-access-layout-within-layout-in-qt