# how to access layout within layout in qt

Tags: qt

I got an error when running my qt program. (*It used to work and can be compiled perfectly before I add this new function `void perfectPanel::aaaf` in order to do something.*) The error message is,

`QLayout::parentWidget: A layout can only have another layout as a parent.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

It happens since I was trying to add a new widget to my layout `gridLayoutSub_`, but layout `gridLayoutSub_` is within another layout called `gridLayout_`

```
void perfectPanel::aaaf()
{
    // some codes ...
    gridLayoutSub_->addWidget(kkk, 6, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

Anyone knows what's going wrong and how to fix it?

### More details: Declarations of these two layouts

In mymainwindow class, there is a dock widget. And in order to customize this dock widget, I wrote a new class called `perfectPanel` which is a subclass of `QWidget`, and then in the constructor of this `perfectPanel`, I have the following codes:

```
groupBoxA = new QGroupBox(tr("groupBoxA"));
QGridLayout* gridLayoutA = new QGridLayout(groupBoxA);

VBoxLayoutPanel = new QVBoxLayout(this);
VBoxLayoutPanel->addWidget(groupBoxA);

groupBoxA->setLayout(gridLayoutA);
setLayout(VBoxLayoutPanel);
```

As you can see, `gridLayoutA` is within another layout `VBoxLayoutPanel`. And the error I mentioned happens when I try to addWidget to gridLayoutA later in function `void perfectPanel::aaaf`, during:

`gridLayoutA->addWidget(kkk, 6, 0, 1, 1);`

### The header of `perfectPanel` class

```
class perfectPanel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit perfectPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~perfectPanel();

private:
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show us when the declaration of the 2 layouts and when you add  gridLayoutSub_ to gridLayout_

Comment: Okay, I have added the lines of my definition of those two layouts. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `perfectPanel` a subclass of `QDockWidget` ?

Comment: It is a subclass of `QWidget`

Comment: the only "problem" I could find is that you are giving widgets to the layouts constructor, and then using `setLayout` which is the same thing AFAIK, but that usually doesn't cause problems

Comment: Run it through a debugger and see if it's crashing on the `addWidget` line or not. Also, when you create `gridLayoutA` you're setting its parent to a QGroupBox, which isn't a subclass of QLayout, and that's probably why you see that warning message about the layout's parent. Tracking down the actual line that causes one of those Qt warnings is always tricky.

Comment: Why I am able to addWidget to `VBoxLayoutPanel`?